# Output a string in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use loop variable as a string and use it directly with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in PL/SQL loop. Here is my code:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE LOWER(table_name) LIKE 'tblequityreturnstest_%'
    )
    LOOP
        vqs := 'DROP TABLE'||i||''
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vqs;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But I am getting an error :

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || member submultiset
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Is the problem really about "output" specifically? Also you should not include the tags in the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, try

```
DECALRE    
   vqs VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE LOWER(table_name) LIKE 'tblequityreturnstest_%') LOOP
      vqs := 'DROP TABLE '||i.table_name;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vqs;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

or even simpler

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE LOWER(table_name) LIKE 'tblequityreturnstest_%') LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||i.table_name;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Yes, I anticipated this. I assumed your code just as a snippet.

Comment: DECLARE
vqs varchar(1000) := '';
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT d.table_name FROM user_tables d WHERE (LOWER(d.table_name) LIKE 'tblequityreturnstest_%')) LOOP
      vqs := 'SET TIMING ON;

SELECT a.Ticker,
FLAnnReturn(ReturnData(a.EquityReturn, '||'Daily'||')) AS AnnReturn
FROM '||i.table_name||' a
GROUP BY a.Ticker
ORDER BY 1;
SET TIMING OFF;';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vqs;
   END LOOP;
END;
/

Comment: For something like this it can be simpler to construct the required DDL in the cursor, or else add a dummy column to the cursor and populate that procedurally in the loop, rather than declaring a separate variable. btw you don't need to assign `null` to a new string variable, as it's already null by default.

Comment: @MuditSharma if you have additional code please add it to the question or start a new one. Just noticed the `SET TIMING IN` in your dynamic SQL string, which is a SQL*Plus command. SQL\*Plus is a separate command-line tool and PL/SQL can't host out to it, or anything else.